# Select all and multiple cursors using SublimeText2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a text file with 100's of news articles.
I need to Select All > Take cursor to the beginning of each line and have the 'multiple cursors' open so I can add some data.

Since the new articles do not have the same begging character, I can not use CTRL+F3.

Is there a way to [CTRL] + [A] (Select All) then > Go to the begging of each line with 'multiple cursors' open ?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You should select all with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Then split the selection into one selection per line with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Then press the left arrow key.

Now you should be able to type data at the beginning of each line.

Comment: cmd+shift+L for mac

Comment: To type at the beginning of each line press HOME button instead of Left arrow key.

Comment: Works great in Sublime Text 3 on OSX Sierra! Thank you.

Comment: ctrl + L , if you wish to select the other side.

Answer (score 3):

Let me add some answer, ( work in sublime 2 / sublime 3 )

i try with **@Riccardo Marotti** step 
, but when the article have tab it will lead to the very far first line

So I make some fix , To make cursor in every front line or every end of line :

> 1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> // select all
> 2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> // Add cursor to all line
> 3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> // put cursor to first word in the line

to get the end of line no need to do the first step again if you are in the first line, just do this one :

> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> // put cursor to end of line, then
>   click "right arrow" to remove the drag

or you can try this one (**really an experimental works**)

> Just use you center of mouse, click it (the center roll of your
>   mouse), then drag, this will lead to add more cursor 
>   , then just press left/right

or try to seek more here :

> [sublime-text-multiple-cursor-shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25827388/sublime-text-multiple-cursor-shortcut)
>
> [override-shortcut-for-multiple-cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900984/how-to-override-shortcut-for-multiple-cursors-sublime-text-3)

hope this help

Comment: Why do you need Shift+End in the first place if you want to get to the end of the line? Just press End lol

Answer (score 1):

I think <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> (or <kbd>up</kbd>) when your cursor is at the beginning of a line might be what you're looking for. It will put the cursor on multiple lines, and what you type will be duplicated on each.

Comment: Ha, that's weird. I'm using win7 as well and it works just fine. In fact, whenever I try that to mess with others' computers it never works.