# how to override shortcut for multiple cursors sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using linux [FEDORA 20]. I want to override shortcut key for multiple cursor which is 
`ctrl+alt+up/down`
because it is used for switching workspace in fedora.
I tired to search shortcut in 
`Preferences>key binding - default`.
 But couldn't find it.
So how do i override it?

Answer (score 14):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for multiple selection in Windows, not Linux. The following is from the Linux keymap file:

```js
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3065, alt+shift+up/down is not for selecting multiple line. I added your lines in `Preferences > User - Keyboard` Binding shortcut to make it work. Thanks it helped.

Comment: Great, thanks! Just don't forget to add [ and ] before the code above

Comment: @euDennis the square brackets weren't added because, as I explained in the answer, the code snippet was from a much larger default file, not an example of what a custom keymap should look like.

Comment: Understood :) I didn't find it on my default file, so I had to add to custom keymap. ;) Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much. I missed this shortcut from mac, this was a hard one to google for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

Go to 
`Preferences > Key Binding - User`
 and add following lines to override default key bindings.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+space+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+space+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} }
```

where

```
ctrl+space+up/down
```

is your key bindings.

Comment: Why not accept one's own answer? It's great. You helped a lot those Ubuntu users (like me) who haven't used much multiple selection in Sublime because of the shortcuts colliding with the Unity workspace hopping